# Confused about some hexadecimals, longs, and int

Tags: scala, integer, long-integer

I am following along my Scala textbook and I see this:

```
scala> val hex = 0x5
hex: Int = 5

scala> val hex2 = 0x00ff
hex2: Int = 255

scala> val hex3 = 0xff
hex2: Int = 255

scala> var hex4 = 0xbe
magic: Int = 190

scala> var hex5 = 0xFF
magic: Int = 255

val magic = 0xcafebabe
magic: Int = -889275714

scala> var prog = 0xCAFEBABEL
prog: Long = 3405691582

scala> val tower = 35l
tower: Long = 35
```

My questions:

1. why do you need the extra `00` after the `x` in `0x00FF`?
2. I get why `FF` = 255... hexadecimal is base16 starting at 00 = 0 and 0F = 15. But why does `0xcafebabe` = -889275714?
3. Why is going on with the Longs? I don't understand what is going on?

Comment: #2 - Positive and negative numbers are stored in a binary format called "two's complement". Read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't, it's just to show that leading 0s are ignored as far as I can tell
2. int is a 32-bit signed integer: if you exceed 2^31, the highest-value bit gets set but is interpreted as a minus. In short, you have an overflow.
3. If you add "l", the variable is a long which uses 64 bits, so the overflow doesn't happen

Answer (score -1):

00FF needs the 2 zeros to make sure that this is a SIGNED number, proving that it is positive by using the two zeros.
 The cafebabe doesn't have that since it is a negative number. We found that out because of the lack of zeros at the end.
Finally, the point of the long (though im not sure of that one) is to set the idea that there are unseen zeros stretching backwards, thus giving us a positive number.

Comment: No. Signed number uses first BIT (not whole hex) for a plus/minus sign. Please do not post answers you are not sure about. Make some research first.